# load google map after getting latitude and longitude from server in angular6 using @agm/core

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-google-maps

I am working in Angular6. I am using "AGM - Angular Google Maps" to draw the map.

I need to draw the map after getting latitude and longitude from the backend.

Please have a look at my code

app.component.ts

```js
private lat:number;
private lng:number;

getSaloon () {
// show loader
this.saloon.vars.displayLoader (true);

// get saloon detail
this.saloon.getSaloon ().subscribe (res => {
  // update saloon-detail
  this.saloonDetail = res.data;

  // set saloon-form values
  this.setSaloonvarmValues ();

  // show loader
  this.saloon.vars.displayLoader (false);

  // show error
  this.saloon.vars.showNotification('Saloon detail successfully found', res.message, 'success');
}, err => {
  // show loader
  this.saloon.vars.displayLoader (false);

  // show error
  this.saloon.vars.showNotification(this.saloon.vars.convertObjectToString (err.errors), err.message);
})
```

}

Saloon.ts

```js
export class Saloon {
    address:string;
    company_number:null;
    contact_number:number;
    header:string;
    id:number;
    lat:number;
    lng:number;
    logo_url:string;
    name:string;
    postal_code:string;
    shop_flag:string;
    standard_price:number;
    vat_number:string;
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<agm-map 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#googleMapAddressModal" 
    [latitude]="lat" 
    [longitude]="lng" 
    [disableDoubleClickZoom]="true" 
    [usePanning]="true" 
    [panControl]="true" 
    [zoomControl]="false" 
    [streetViewControl]="false">
              <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Comment: which problem do you have? your map is drawing before you get data?

Comment: Yes, Otherwise it set latitude, longitude as 0 by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You simply add an `*ngIf` like this:

```
<agm-map *ngIf="lat && lng" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#googleMapAddressModal" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [disableDoubleClickZoom]="true" [usePanning]="true" [panControl]="true" [zoomControl]="false" [streetViewControl]="false">
              <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

You could need to adjust init `lat` and `lng` values, but I hope the idea is clear

Comment: Thank to give time. But I already tried this approach and it is not working.

Comment: can you describe your problem or what happens?

Comment: When I tried your suggestion, map-screen had No map data. 

I need to initialize map after getting data from the backend.

Comment: I can't understand. if you add an ngIf you should see nothing about map, right? Then it appears when you get lat and lng data. So what is your desired behaviour? You can set temp lat and lng?